# echarts display corresponding legend for each bar

Tags: web, charts, echarts

echarts version 3.5.4

I created a bar chart, and I want to display corresponding legend for each bar.
However, it seems that the legend can only be displayed for series.

For example, I have a series and it has six data items. That means six bars will be shown. So how can I display a legend for each of these six bars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you just can't display corresponding legend for each bar.

In chart without axis like `pie`, `funnel` , you can display legend for each data,

like this [demo](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=pie-simple)

In chart with axis like `line`, `bar`, you can only display legend for each series,

like this [demo](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=bar-brush)

------addition ----

> can we make each bar a separate series, and then make the chart look the same as only one series?

Yes, check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/IanZhong/h5v3ps1c/81/)

However, some key points should be noticed to achieve this,

- first, `data` of every `series` must have same length, so `null` value should be used as complement.
- in order to have suitable bar width, every `series` must use `stack` option.

```js
let echartsObj = echarts.init(document.querySelector('#canvas'));


 option = {
     color: ['#3398DB', '#5528DB', '#ff00DB', '#3300DB', '#de3423'],
  
     xAxis : [
         {
             type : 'category',
             data : ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
         }
     ],
     legend: {
      data: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5', 'data6']
     },
     yAxis : [
         {
             type : 'value'
         }
     ],
     series : [
         {
             name:'data1',
             type:'bar',
            stack: 'stack',
             data:[10, , , , ,,,]
         }, {
             name:'data2',
             type:'bar',
       stack: 'stack',
             data:[, 22, , , ,,,]
         }, {
             name:'data3',
             type:'bar',
       stack: 'stack',
             data:[, , 35, , ,,,]
         }, {
             name:'data4',
             type:'bar',
       stack: 'stack',
             data:[, , , 70, ,,,]
         }, {
             name:'data5',
             type:'bar',
       stack: 'stack',
             data:[, , , , 155,,,]
         },  {
             name:'data6',
             type:'bar',
             stack: 'stack',
             data:[, , , , ,40,,]
         }
     ]
 };
  echartsObj.setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
      <header>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/echarts/4.1.0.rc2/echarts-en.min.js"></script>
      </header>
      <body>
        <div id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 200px">
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So can we make each bar a separate series, and then make the chart look the same as only one series?

Comment: @wayen yes, that can be achieved,  check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/IanZhong/h5v3ps1c/76/),  detail is added to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the solution I want. You're an angel and saved my afternoon.